# How can I convert a 1d array to a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am running the code below.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold

###############################################################################

start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)

df.rename(columns = {'ticker':'Ticker', 'Adj Close':'Close'}, inplace = True) 
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape
#df.reset_index()

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

open = np.array([df.Open]).astype(np.float)
close = np.array([df.Close]).astype(np.float)

# The daily variations of the quotes are what carry most information
variation = (close - open)
```

The code above gives me this 1d array, here.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
0   0.38    0.93    0.3 0.72    -0.42   0.37    0.36    0.71    0.89    -0.32   0.11    -0.06   -0.17   0.4 0.25    -0.48   0.1 -0.29   -0.29   -0.38   0.21    0.22    0.11    -0.01   -0.07   -0.66   0   -0.78   0.24    -0.89   0.07
```

My desired output would be a 2d array, like this.

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
0   0.38    0.93    0.3     0.72    -0.42   0.37    0.36    0.71    0.89    -0.32   0.11    
1   0.61    0.18    0.63    0.02    -0.03   -0.27   -0.75   -1      0.48    -0.74   -0.34   
2   1.77    0.95    1.69    2.05    -1.36   2.25    1.83    -0.8    1.35    -0.99   -1.35   
3   0.7     -0.12   0.32    -0.14   -0.53   0.63    0.85    0.46    0.23    -0.83   0.59    
4   1.71    -0.8    0.74    -0.58   -1.2    0.38    0.35    0.06    0.56    -0.38   0.64    
5   0.47    0.25    0.93    -0.9    -0.15   0.64    -0.11   -0.09   0.44    -0.47   -0.09
```

How can I change my 1d array to a 2d array, with the difference between open and close horizontal, and different stock open-close vertical?  Thanks?

Comment: can you post your  `close` and `open`?

Comment: Why are you switching from Pandas to NumPy, especially in a seemingly needlessly complex way? As an aside, why use `.`/dot/attribute style for column access, instead of `[ ]`?

Comment: Well, close and open come straight from the code.  The code dynamically downloads historical stock price information from Yahoo Finance.  Open is: array([[201.49000549, 199.00999451, 200.72000122, ...,  60.49000168,
         59.91999817,  60.20000076]])  Close is: array([[192.66822815, 193.68403625, 194.56436157, ...,  60.40000153,
         60.88999939,  58.47999954]])

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work.  Apparently you have to store items in a list rather than a dataframe.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold


start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['AXP',
        'AAPL',
        'BA',
        'CAT',
        'CSCO',
        'CVX',
        'XOM',
        'GS',
        'HD',
        'IBM',
        'INTC',
        'JNJ',
        'KO',
        'JPM',
        'MCD',
        'MMM',
        'MRK',
        'MSFT',
        'NKE',
        'PFE',
        'PG',
        'TRV',
        'UNH',
        'UTX',
        'VZ',
        'V',
        'WBA',
        'WMT',
        'DIS']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()

#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

open = np.array([q['Open'] for q in price_data]).astype(np.float)
close = np.array([q['Adj Close'] for q in price_data]).astype(np.float)

#close_prices = np.array([q.close for q in quotes]).astype(np.float)

# The daily variations of the quotes are what carry most information
variation = (close - open)


# pd.DataFrame(variation).to_csv("C:\\path\\file.csv")

# Learn a graphical structure from the correlations
edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV()
X = variation

# standardize the time series: using correlations rather than covariance
# is more efficient for structure recovery
X = variation.copy().T
X /= X.std(axis=0)
edge_model.fit(X)


# Cluster using affinity propagation

_, labels = cluster.affinity_propagation(edge_model.covariance_)
n_labels = labels.max()


details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(tickers,labels)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```